# Closing SSRS after rendering a file into excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, rendering, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS Report that I call from another application. Basically, I pass the filtering parameters, etc into a web call.

We recently got a request to automatically render it as an Excel file.

```
http://10.164.80.117/ReportServer_TEST?%2FPeriodic+Report&rs:Command=Render&Company=TEST+1&YEAR=2015&rc:Toolbar=False&rs:Format=Excel
```

All well and good, but once the render is complete, the newly opened tab is just left open and blank. Is there a way to create the excel sheet, download it and then close the newly opened tab?